# (ubuntu) nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: permission denied)

Tags: nginx, bind

I need help figuring out the root cause of this permission denied error. What permissions does nginx need? Why is it so complicated?

Comment: It's selinux. See my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22746255/90442

Answer (score 32):

the socket API bind() to a port less than 1024, such as 80 as your title mentioned, need root access.

here is "[Bind to ports less than 1024 without root access](https://serverfault.com/questions/268099/bind-to-ports-less-than-1024-without-root-access)"

and another easier way is to run nginx as root.

Answer (score 23):

If you use a port bigger than 1024 with root privilege, but still got this problem, that's may be caused by `SELinux`:

Check this port, say 8024, in segange port

```
sudo semanage port -l | grep http_port_t
```

If 8024 doesn't exist in the port list, add it into segange port

```
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t  -p tcp 8024
```

###update in 2017.12.22

Sometimes your SELinux is `disabled`, you need to `enforcing` it first. Check the status of SELinux by

`$ sestatus`

More steps can read this wonderful article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7-part-1-basic-concepts

Answer (score 3):

nginx needs root access. Just use

> sudo nginx

next step along with your password

Comment: I am genuinely curious if it is safe to sudo nginx or not.

Comment: I don't know whether it's safe or not. But, the non-root users should need sudo privileges to start nginx. You can refer below link to know how to secure nginx.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: no, nginx does not need root access. but *anything* that want to use ports between 0-1024 needs root access, and his nginx was configured to listen on port 80. anything that tries to listen to port 80 needs root access. reconfigure nginx to listen on port 1025 instead, and no root access is needed.

Comment: This may be dangerous. If NginX gets compromised by a security issue, attacker may gain superuser access immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If see this msg after run "nginx -t", you dont have premission run as root "sudo nginx -t"

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be:

1) add user to sudoers ( my user is prod)

```
usermod -aG sudo prod
```

2) inside circus ( process manager ) append sudo before nginx executable, mine looks like this:

```
[watcher:nginx]
cmd = sudo /usr/sbin/nginx
args = -c /home/t/Projects/x_b_11/etc/nginx.conf -p /home/t/Projects/x_b_11
```

3) and finaly add line into file /etc/sudoers ( my user is prod). This line avoids error (sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified). Probably need to restart session ( reboot). Enjoy.

```
prod ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/nginx
```

Comment: Running the app using `sudo` seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses AppArmor and not SELinux. The responses pointing to SELinux may not be that relevant to the OP.

For the others that Googled this: I also encountered this issue on a SELinux-enabled CentOS 7 machine. nginx would not bind port 80 and gave me error *13: permission denied* despite having already run
`setcap 'CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+ep' /usr/sbin/nginx` to allow the service to bind the port with a non-root user.

Temporarily setting SELinux to Permissive (`sudo setenforce Permissive`) allowed nginx to start. I then ran `audit2allow -a` which gave me

```
#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'httpd_can_network_connect'
allow httpd_t ntop_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
```

Which meant the solution was to also run:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

After which you can set SELinux back to Enforcing (`sudo setenforce Enforcing`) and restart everything to verify.